# Add a - into a MVC3 controller name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

This might be a stupid question but I want to add a - into a controller name e.g. feature-request

How do I do this? I have tried creating one with a view however it can't be found.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using the standard conventions in the MVC framework, **you can't**. Why? Because C# (actually .NET itself) doesn't support `-` in type names.

I suspect you want this to allow your users to go to http://yoursite.com/feature-request/add or something - in that case, just add a route that sends them to the correct place.

```
routes.Map("FeatureRequestsRoute", "~/feature-requests/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "FeatureRequest", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Be sure to add the routes in the correct order - the default route matches *anything*, so this route has to be added *before* the default route.